# Applying styles to an entire app or activity

Tags: android, android-styles

In an Android book I have it says that themes can be applied to and entire activity or an entire application. It doesn't show how but the Android docs say to simply put the theme statement into the androidmanifest.xml file like so....

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:theme="@style/bigred"  . . . .
```

but it doesn't work. Only the application bar is styled with the big red type and the text in other widgets is not styled at all. How is this supposed to be done?

Also the docs say that to see what styles are available from Android to read the code! Any better docs than this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these tutorials it also helped me.[customized-title](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/) and [customized-title](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-create-custom-titlebar).

Answer (score 0):

Try using **actionbarsherlock**.Go through their sample codes from [this](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) website.

Answer (score 0):

Please review the following: [`How to Apply Styles to the all UI in Android`](https://sites.google.com/site/ramkiranworks/customization/Themes.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)